# web.xml validation in Weblogic throws error because of cookie-config

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, weblogic, web.xml

I have the follwing web.xml for an application.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>..</display-name>

<description>..</description>



<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>SESSIONDEBUG_JSESSIONID</name>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I get the following error upon deployment

```
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'session-timeout@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'cookie-    config@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element session-    config@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
```

Not sure I fully understand the error. I see that it wants me to declare session-timeout in there. I'll give that a try..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `<cookie-config>` is [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html) in [Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) and not supported in older versions such as 2.5. Your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.5.

You've 2 options:

1. Redeclare `web.xml` conform Servlet 3.0 (which implicitly also requires a Servlet 3.0 compatible target container such as Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, WebLogic 12, etc).
2. If you can't upgrade, then forget it and solve it using a custom servlet filter or container-specific configuration (e.g. a `Valve` in Tomcat/JBoss; can't answer off top of head for WebLogic as I've never really used it, consider asking a new question for that part).

Comment: How can I declare the web-common_3_0.xsd in my web.xml? I upgraded my web.xml to 3.0 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

Comment: That's pretty much it, but you should absolutely understand that this would still fail if your target container is not a Servlet 3.0 compatible one. It should be at least WebLogic 12. If it's an older WebLogic version and you can't upgrade it, then it's end of story.

Comment: It still fails on Weblogic 12.1. The Servlet 3 implementation of at least some WL12.1 versions is incomplete.