# Multiple session cookie names in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jsessionid

I have multiple projects on different server instances, since they have different session cookie names. The names are set on the `Dorg.apache.catalina.JSESSIONID` VM argument.

So, my question is: is there any way to set this variable application wise, in the same server instance?

Answer (score 0):

how about configuring the cookie name in the web.xml?

This requires the use of Servlet 3.0 or newer, but you can see the trick here:
[web.xml validation in Weblogic throws error because of cookie-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536503/web-xml-validation-in-weblogic-throws-error-because-of-cookie-config)

Comment: Unfortunately using Servlet 3.0 is out of question :(