# how to remove jsessionid in the url (Java)?

Tags: java, jboss, jsessionid

I need help, how can I hide the jsessionid from the url?
Use jboss 5.0 and web app version 2.5.
In the context on jboss I have

> SessionCookie secure = "true"
>
> httpOnly = "true"

Can you help me?
"`secure`" and "`httpOnly`" must remain set to true

Exmple url : `http://localhost:8080/actionMenuGeneral.do;jsessionid=EA9073194BEDF67C16BEE48600B97737`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change the following in application's web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

More details at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/338313

Comment: I added the tags, but the following error appears:  
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'cookie-config'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536503/web-xml-validation-in-weblogic-throws-error-because-of-cookie-config